# can a SELECT Column value be used in a subquery?

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to use the HeaderID value in the UsageCounts Select() query?

```
    SELECT HeaderID, HeaderName, HeaderFileName, CreatedDate, UsageCounts = (

        SELECT 
    COUNT(ClassXML.value('(/Data/prpID)[1]', 'INT'))
    FROM CustomContent 
    WHERE ClassXML.value('(/Data/prpID)[1]', 'INT') = HeaderID

)
 FROM Headers
```

This is SQL Server 2008 R2

Update: I guess I am getting a result set.. it just took 8 mins. Any improvements?

Comment: to improve performance, probably get the headerid, count from XML content in CTE and then join with Headers table.

Comment: That may not help. CTEs are like functions, each time you see one in a query it can be re-run.

Comment: probably store the subquery result in temp table as XML extraction is slow in sql server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a join instead of a subquery to speed it up. Something like this:

```
Select 
    HeaderID,  
    max(HeaderName) HeaderName,  
    max(HeaderFileName) HeaderFileName,  
    max(CreatedDate) CreatedDate,  
    COUNT(ClassXML.value('(/Data/prpID)[1]', 'INT')) UsageCounts  
From Headers  
Left Join CustomContent on  
     ClassXML.value('(/Data/prpID)[1]', 'INT') = HeaderID  
Group by  
    HeaderID
```

Note: I'm assuming you only have 1 HeaderName, HeaderFileName and Created for each HeaderID

Answer (score 4):

Give `Alias name` and use it inside `correlated Subquery`.

```
SELECT HeaderID,
       HeaderName,
       HeaderFileName,
       CreatedDate,
       UsageCounts =(SELECT Count(ClassXML.value('(/Data/prpID)[1]', 'INT'))
                      FROM   CustomContent A
                      WHERE  ClassXML.value('(/Data/prpID)[1]', 'INT') = H.HeaderID) 
FROM   Headers H
```